# Why does chakra-ui colorMode become "dark" when I refresh the page in nextjs example app?

Tags: next.js, chakra-ui

I am running 'with-chakra-ui' from the [nextjs example](https://github.com/vercel/next.js/tree/canary/examples/with-chakra-ui).

https://stackblitz.com/github/vercel/next.js/tree/canary/examples/with-chakra-ui

Colormode switch does work well. But when I refresh the page, it always returns to the darkmode like this video.

[Video Link](https://user-images.githubusercontent.com/64240134/153132073-e2cffec4-07db-4c3e-ada5-2404e82129d1.mp4)

I want to remember the color mode.

How can I do this?

Comment: Oh, I found why it returned to the darkmode

in the _app.tsx,
ColorModeProvider option was {useSystemColorMode: true}
change it to false, then the page can remember the color mode

Comment: Consider adding a response to your question add accept it.

Comment: Oh, I didn't know I could do it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Oh, I found why it returned to the darkmode.

In the _app.tsx, ColorModeProvider option was {useSystemColorMode: true}.

Change it to false, then the page can remember the color mode.

Comment: You then should be able to accept your answer. It may take some time for the option to be available.